# AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate: No active and enabled video connection'

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Hi I am fairly new to coding and I ran into this error with AVCapturePhotoOutput. I am using Swift 5 and Xcode 12.5.1. I'm running it on my actual device and I have been stuck on it for awhile. The error only occurs when I try to capture a photo. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you :)

```
private let output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
private let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

private let cameraView = UIView()
```

t

```
private func setUpCamera() {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
        do {
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(output) {
            captureSession.addOutput(output)
        }
        

        // Layer
        previewLayer.session = captureSession
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
        self.captureSession = captureSession
           
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
        
    }
}
```

t

```
Extension CameraViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation(),
          let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        return
    }
    
    captureSession?.stopRunning()
    showEditPhoto(image: image)
}

private func showEditPhoto(image: UIImage) {
    guard let resizedImage = image.sd_resizedImage(
        with: CGSize(width: 640, height: 640),
        scaleMode: .aspectFill
    ) else {
        return
    }

    let vc = PostEditViewController(image: resizedImage)
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        vc.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: What is the error. Where does it occur in the code?

Comment: Could you leave a little more insight on the error /warning? where does it occur?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error only shows up on @main in the App Delegate like this Thread 1: "*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] No active and enabled video connection". But doesn't actually show up as an error until I try to capture a picture. No errors pop up beforehand before using that feature

Answer (score 0):

Try using ‘ cgImageRepresentation()’ instead of ‘ fileDataRepresentation()’. And init a UIImage from the given cgImage